# Is there a way to alter result of an odata after query is applied and before data is returned?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I have a WebAPI `OData` controller that I need to do some operation after query applied and before data is returned. In the `EnableQuery` I can not an extension method to do that.

Indeed I need to remove some record before data is returned to client. This operation can not be done via URI/Query/Filter.

Update

see following code. actual filter is applied on the return value of first `ApplyQuery` If I do my filter inside it, uri filter is ignore.

Code that I tried to see if an extensions exists:

```
    public class EQueryAttribute : EnableQueryAttribute
{
    public override IQueryable ApplyQuery(IQueryable queryable, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)
    {
            var retval = base.ApplyQuery(queryable, queryOptions);

        if (queryable.ElementType.Name == "ProductInfoDto")
        {
            var q = retval as IQueryable<ProductInfoDto>;
            return new List<ProductInfoDto>() { new ProductInfoDto { PasName = "123" } }.AsQueryable();
        }

        return retval;

    }

    public override object ApplyQuery(object entity, ODataQueryOptions queryOptions)
    {
        return base.ApplyQuery(entity, queryOptions);
    }

    public override Task OnActionExecutedAsync(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {

        return base.OnActionExecutedAsync(actionExecutedContext, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Comment: Provide some code you have tried, you can use Query option.

Comment: @Aria see update plz

Comment: So you want to remove some specific records? if yes you can remove it in your Quaryable func before returning records or add your filter to `queryOption`. take a look [here](https://github.com/OData/WebApi/issues/555)

Comment: @Aria I update code again